# Where is the error in my nested MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I am guessing there is a mistake in the nested query however I cannot seem to find it myself.
Here is the query:

```
Select student.sid, name 
from student join exam on exam.sid = student.sid
where student.sid in (select *
                from course join exam on cid=courseid 
                group by exam.sid
                having sum(credits) >= 20)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group by` as follows:

```
select s.sid, s.name 
from student s 
Join exam e on s.sid = e.sid
Join course c on c.cid = e.courseid
group by s.sid, s.name
having sum(c.credits) >= 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a mistake.  The nested query is returning multiple columns but the comparison is to only a single column.

This will obviously generate an error. Presumably, you don't want the `sum()` but without sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing, it is hard to make a concrete suggestion.

The query may have other errors, but presumably, you intend something like this:

```
select s.sid, s.name 
from student s 
where s.sid in (select e.sid, 
                from course c join
                     exam e
                     on c.cid = e.courseid 
                group by e.sid
                having sum(c.credits) >= 20
               )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! The query was supposed to show the following: Id and name of the students who passed exams for a total amount of at least 20 credits

Comment: Does that mean that a nested query can only return one column?

Comment: @Chiara . . . No.  MySQL supports tuples.  And `exists` allows any number of columns, although it ignores the values in them (I just use `exists (select 1 . . . )`.